# Is ROBLOX Lua allowed on code review?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-language

I've recently gotten more interest in roblox lua, and I was wondering if code review allows it. Here's an example piece of code I want to share, but I fear that it could be closed as off-topic.

`function onClicked()
if script.Parent.Parent.iBusControlSystem.iBus.Enabled == true then`

```
if script.Parent.Parent.iBusControlSystem.An.Value == 0 then
    script.Parent.Parent.iBusControlSystem.DestinationChange:Play()
    script.Parent.Parent.Interface.SurfaceGui.Frame.Announcement.Text = "The destination has changed. Listen for more info"
    wait(7)
    script.Parent.Parent.Interface.SurfaceGui.Frame.Announcement.Text = "Welcome aboard London United's bus"
    for i=1, #c do
        if c[i].Name == "iBusPassenger" then
            c[i].SurfaceGui.iBus.Visible = true
            c[i].SurfaceGui.iBus.Text = "The destination of this bus has changed"`
```

I got really bored one day so I decided to make it.

So anyway, is roblox lua allowed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. We have plenty of [lua](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lua) questions.  I don't see any reason why a Lua question using the ROBLOX API would inherently be off-topic.  Just follow the standard [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Comment: Thank you! I'll post one later today